# MEAN js dynamic title

Tags: node.js, meanjs

how to add dynamic title for each pages of the MEAN js application. in the layout.server.js has defined the title as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
```

so how can we make dynamic title?

Comment: You can set it in your `routes`. What view engine are you using?

Comment: Have you noticed `{{ }}` around the title? It is already dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some people might be mislead thinking that besides it is already dynamic, it can be changed and it is controlled by angular out of the box because of having an expression with `{{ }}` but that's not quite true.

In fact `{{title}}` could mean an expression that should be evaluated against `scope.title`, however if you take a deeper look at MEAN.js you will see that it is using the swig template engine which also uses `{{ }}` to define variables. **In this case, `{{title}}` is NOT an angular expression, it is a swig variable** which was passed via express/swig and it can be changed in the `config/env/default.js` (in MEAN.js 0.4.0).

If you want the title to be changed in the frontend (i.e. possible to change it within angular logic) you have to assign a scope variable to the title element or use a custom directive. Even if, at first, the title value is the one defined using express/swig, angular can take control afterwards and change it accordingly to your needs.

One solution could be to define the title in your angular states like this:

```
.state('some-state', {
    url: '/someurl',
    templateUrl: 'some-path-to-view',
    data: {
        title: 'My new title',
    }
  })
```

And then listen for the `$stateChangeSuccess` event to set the title:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    console.log(toState.data.title); // Prints the new title to the console
    // Set the title    
});
```

**EDIT:** First paragraph rewritten for more coherence.

Comment: Well, it is still *dynamic* even if value comes from different place.

Comment: In the current meanjs state it *has support* for dynamic titles but it's static unless you add code to the server routes explicitly changing the variable or add code in angular states as I wrote in the answer. Otherwise the title will just be the one defined in the server default env config.

Comment: No. In the context of the page source `<title>{{title}}</title>` is dynamic and `<title>title</title>` is static. Here, dynamic means that this is a variable which might be substituted for some value.

Comment: I didn't use the right words in my last comment. What I'm trying to say is that despite being able to change the title since it is a swig variable (dynamic) it will always have the same value unless you add some code. I believe the user who asked the question knows the title is changeable, he saw the variable {{title}} and probably saw the title bar always with the same value 'MEAN.JS' which led him to ask the question.

Comment: OP question wasn't very clear. Good that you understood what they want to achieve, but saying that `{{ }}` isn't dynamic is somehow incorrect.

Comment: @AleksandrM I edited my answer regarding that aspect. Should be more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted question, in the MeanJS stack you can do the following:

Create a new view in the `modules/core/client/views` ex. `title.client.view.html`.

In the file `title.client.view.html` you can get the title by doing:

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderController">
   <span>{{$state.current.data.pageTitle}}</span>
</div>
```

The HeaderController has a `$state` variable that contains the current state title specified in:

```
.state('some-state', {
url: '/someurl',
templateUrl: 'some-path-to-view',
data: {
    title: 'My new title',
}})
```

Then to get the title in the `modules/core/server/views/layout.server.view.html` file you include `title.client.view.html` like this:

`<div ng-include="'/modules/core/client/views/title.client.view.html'"></div>`

This will render the title of a state dynamically as you navigate.

Answer (score -1):

The MEAN.JS page title is already dynamic and can be found at modules/core/client/directives/page-title.client.directive.js:

```
function listener(event, toState) {
        var applicationCoreTitle = 'MEAN.js',
          separator = ' - ',
          stateTitle = applicationCoreTitle + separator;
```

Whereas 'MEAN.js' is the default page title and can be changed accordingly.